# Interactive visualization in 3D using non-flash technologies?

Tags: html, canvas, 3d

How can one recreate the 3D feeling of this interactive visualization (done in Flash) in HTML5/SVG/Canvas or similar? Are there any JS libraries you can recommend?

http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/interactive/2011/mar/22/middle-east-protest-interactive-timeline

Answer (score 1):

This is not actually 3D, just 2D with perspective.

Many libraries such as D3js (http://d3js.org) aid in making such visualizations, using either Canvas or SVG.

Even for true 3D there are several canvas libraries, the most popular of which is Three.js (http://threejs.org/)

Comment: Thanks. So you think the feel can be recreated using D3? Even with the curved plane fading away and the smooth animation? I am skeptical but would love to be convinced :=) Any ideas on how to go about?